# Spring boot , Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-boot

Searched over the net but unable to find the satisfying approach.
I am new to spring boot and aware of starter dependancies,
I want to develop a springboot app using elastic search as a storage system.
Wherever i searched i found that somewhere my service class will have to implement some interface from springframework for ES crud operations.
Is there any other way without implementing or extending the components.
I myself want to create transport client and want to query ES by my code or methods not by overidden ones.
Please if you ahve ever seen any projects you can redirect me to that link .
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming I understand you correctly, you can use the Elasticsearch REST client: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/current/java-rest-low.html

You supply the JSON entities for the queries and parse the responses yourself.  Its pretty basic in what it does, so you're not dependent on a lot of third party stuff to perform operations.

Comment: Thanks @ryanluntgen , It was a success after using client ,
I tried it from ES Template as well.
Thanks alot.